# What is the best way to solve the UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION?

Tags: android, exception, build.gradle

When I make the application use many libraries. I usualy meet a error is `UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION`

This error have some reason as:

- Number function > 65k, we need enable multidex for it
- There are some libs is nested, we need add exclude in build.gradle.

About second case, it is very difficult to detect what is the lib have been nested.

If you have experience on this issue, please share me.

UPDATE:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.48.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.48.jar')
    //    compile 'com.obsez.android.lib.filechooser:filechooser:1.1.2'
    //    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'cn.lightsky.infiniteindicator:library:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.15'
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev170-1.20.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:2.4.1'
}
```

Comment: There isn't a best way because the reason can be different. There is a solution for each case with UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION.
Post your issue and some user will help you to resolve

Comment: Hi Mr @GabrieleMariotti, I have update for my case, it make me long time, so that I want ask about general case.

Comment: Post the stacktrace of the gradle issue. Use gradlew assemble --info to get more detail.

Comment: Hi, Gradlew --info no error  and In logcat only error: ``Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2``

Comment: Unluckly it doesn't help. Near the  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION should be a short description of the real issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best ways to solve UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION?
 I will suggest you for this **Two** step to solve this.

- Check the attached libraries Dependency/hierarchy
- Check which library class or files are cause of the duplication
  files or methods count exceed 65k

- **How to Check attached libraries Dependency/hierarchy ?**

First found the dependency which is used in library which is attached/compiled from the maven/jcenter/mavencentral.Major issue will come with support because it may possible that support-v4 & appcompact already contains in library which is attached from maven (like play service  contains v4 ,appcompact attached then no need to attach support-v4 as it already contains.)

**How to check Dependency/hierarchy** of the attached library in gradle

**Gradle menu > :modulename >> Tasks >> android >> Run "androidDependcies"**

*OR*

**Gradle menu > :app >> Tasks >> android >> Run "androidDependcies"**

By doing so in **Gradle Console** you will get something like below as a output(output may depends on libraries attached) .Which can give idea about duplication/hierarchy of the libraries

```
release
+--- LOCAL: picasso-2.5.2.jar
+--- LOCAL: YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar
+--- LOCAL: commons-lang-2.6.jar
+--- LOCAL: signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar
+--- LOCAL: kxml2_2.3.0.jar
+--- LOCAL: classes.jar
+--- LOCAL: signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar
+--- LOCAL: json-simple-1.1.1.jar
+--- LOCAL: universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar
+--- LOCAL: linkedin-j-.jar
+--- LOCAL: maps.jar
+--- LOCAL: nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.3.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.3.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.3.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.3.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.3.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.3.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|    |         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.3.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.3.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.3.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.3.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|    |         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.3.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.3.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.3.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.3.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
\--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1
     \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
          \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
```

You can also check this from terminal for the above process .

```
gradlew app:dependencies
```

***You can check below image as "picture is worth a thousand words"***

[image: picture is worth a thousand words]

***How to check which class or files causing duplicate entry/or method count exceed 65k ?***

Rather than checking on message or error which you are getting **Message** tab of android studio check it in **Gradle Console**

If in message error is like while transferring classes to dex `:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug` or `:app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease` maximum chances are like because of Multiple dex (method excess 65k limit).

Or if any other error than it will specify like duplicate entry related etc.