# app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug apk build issue

Tags: android

When I try to build apk android studio gives me this error.

Can anyone has any idea about this error?

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: permissions/dispatcher/GrantableRequest.class

Comment: refer this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968171/android-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug-failed-zipexception-dupli

Comment: post your build.gradle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PermissionsDispatcher library thn its mentioned as issue for duplicate class entry.

[How to Check attached libraries Dependency/hierarchy ? which causes duplicate entry for libraries.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35571144/1140237)

In your case you need to make changes as per mentioned in libraries known issue.

```
 compile 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.0.3'
 compile 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:2.0.3'
```

Make changes as per below

```
compile 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.0.3'
apt 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:2.0.3'
```

For more details on duplicate entry issue please check [this](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher/issues/77)

***UPDATE***
Its required to define apt dependecies in root level `build.gradle` file also

check [this](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher/blob/master/build.gradle) for root level build.gradle file declaration.

Let me know if anything

Comment: now m getting this error

Error:(43, 0) Could not find method apt() for arguments [com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:2.0.3] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: @umarfarooq you need to define `apt` dependencies in application's top level `builld.gradle` file also .  `classpath "com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8"`